# Python Code Not Selecting Correct Dictionary

Tags: python, json, function, loops, dictionary

I am trying to loop through and select the two `class_id` values I want, and then compare their `center_x` and `center_y` values together. If they are within a certain range, which I now have set at 0.10 it will print within range. However when I run my code now and print out the  `x_absolute_dif` and `y_absolute_dif` between them it just outputs `0.0` meaning it is not selecting them properly. Any help would be appreaciated.

Python Code:

```py
    desired_id1 = 14
    for thing in results:
        for object1 in thing["objects"]:
            if object1["class_id"] == desired_id1:
                specific_class = object1
                print("Correct Class")
                break

    for _class in results:
        for object1 in _class["objects"]:
            relative_coordinates = object1["relative_coordinates"]
            center_x = relative_coordinates["center_x"]
            center_y = relative_coordinates["center_y"]
            # Do something with these values

    desired_id2 = 15
    for thing in results:
        for object2 in thing["objects"]:
            if object2["class_id"] == desired_id2:
                specific_class = object2
                print("Correct Class")
                break

    for _class in results:
        for object2 in _class["objects"]:
            relative_coordinates = object2["relative_coordinates"]
            center_x = relative_coordinates["center_x"]
            center_y = relative_coordinates["center_y"]
            # Do something with these values

    x_dif = object1["relative_coordinates"]["center_x"] - object2["relative_coordinates"]["center_x"]
    x_absolute_dif = abs(x_dif)
    print(x_absolute_dif)

    if (x_absolute_dif <= 0.10):
        print("X-Cords Within Range") 
        x_within_range = True
    else:
        print("X-Cords Not Within Range")

    y_dif = object1["relative_coordinates"]["center_y"] - object2["relative_coordinates"]["center_y"]
    y_absolute_dif = abs(y_dif)
    print(y_absolute_dif)

    if (y_absolute_dif <= 0.10):
        print("Y-Cords Within Range")
        y_within_range = True
    else:
        print("Y-Cords Not Within Range")
```

Json File:

```
[
    {
        "frame_id": 1,
        "filename": "C:\\Yolo_v4\\darknet\\build\\darknet\\x64\\f047.png",
        "objects": [
               {
                "class_id": 14,
                "name": "d",
                "relative_coordinates": {
                    "center_x": 0.049905,
                    "center_y": 0.635935,
                    "width": 0.101077,
                    "height": 0.044067
                },
                "confidence": 0.966701
            },
            {
                "class_id": 15,
                "name": "e",
                "relative_coordinates": {
                    "center_x": 0.045943,
                    "center_y": 0.685398,
                    "width": 0.109195,
                    "height": 0.041489
                },
                "confidence": 0.923188
            },
            ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem with the code is using `object1` and `object2` which are initialised in the loop and outside the loop they will have the value of the last element before the loop ends. In your case the loops

```
for _class in results:
    for object1 in _class["objects"]:
```

and

```
for _class in results:
    for object2 in _class["objects"]:
```

will leave `object1` and `object2` equal to the last element in `_class["objects"]` and not your desired state (the one after break).

Edit:

```
desired_id1 = 14
obj1 = None
for thing in results:
    for object1 in thing["objects"]:
        if object1["class_id"] == desired_id1:
            specific_class = object1
            obj1 = object1
            print("Correct Class")
            break

for _class in results:
    for object1 in _class["objects"]:
        relative_coordinates = object1["relative_coordinates"]
        center_x = relative_coordinates["center_x"]
        center_y = relative_coordinates["center_y"]
        # Do something with these values

desired_id2 = 15
obj2 = None
for thing in results:
    for object2 in thing["objects"]:
        if object2["class_id"] == desired_id2:
            specific_class = object2
            obj2 = object2
            print("Correct Class")
            break

for _class in results:
    for object2 in _class["objects"]:
        relative_coordinates = object2["relative_coordinates"]
        center_x = relative_coordinates["center_x"]
        center_y = relative_coordinates["center_y"]
        # Do something with these values

x_dif = obj1["relative_coordinates"]["center_x"] - obj2["relative_coordinates"]["center_x"]
x_absolute_dif = abs(x_dif)
print(x_absolute_dif)

if (x_absolute_dif <= 0.10):
    print("X-Cords Within Range") 
    x_within_range = True
else:
    print("X-Cords Not Within Range")

y_dif = obj1["relative_coordinates"]["center_y"] - obj2["relative_coordinates"]["center_y"]
y_absolute_dif = abs(y_dif)
print(y_absolute_dif)

if (y_absolute_dif <= 0.10):
    print("Y-Cords Within Range")
    y_within_range = True
else:
    print("Y-Cords Not Within Range")
```

Comment: What should I change the code to then? Just back to `object`?

Comment: After `specific_class = object1` add `obj1 = object1` and `obj2 = object2` after `specific_class = object2`. Then when you compute `x_dif` and `y_dif` use `obj1` and `obj2`

Comment: Can you put that in your actual answer so it is formatted properly?

Answer (score 0):

Repeated code indicates you should write a function and test it for returning the correct results.  Your loops keep going and don't stop went the coordinates are found.

```py
import json

json_string = r'''[
    {
        "frame_id": 1,
        "filename": "C:\\Yolo_v4\\darknet\\build\\darknet\\x64\\f047.png",
        "objects": [
               {
                "class_id": 14,
                "name": "d",
                "relative_coordinates": {
                    "center_x": 0.049905,
                    "center_y": 0.635935,
                    "width": 0.101077,
                    "height": 0.044067
                },
                "confidence": 0.966701
            },
            {
                "class_id": 15,
                "name": "e",
                "relative_coordinates": {
                    "center_x": 0.045943,
                    "center_y": 0.685398,
                    "width": 0.109195,
                    "height": 0.041489
                },
                "confidence": 0.923188
            }
            ]
    }
]'''

results = json.loads(json_string)

class ValueNotFoundError(Exception): ...

def get_xy(results,desired_id):
    for r in results:
        for o in r['objects']:
            if o['class_id'] == desired_id:
                rc = o['relative_coordinates']
                return rc['center_x'],rc['center_y'] # return results immediately
    # if not found...
    raise ValueNotFoundError

def check(label,a,b,tolerance):
    if (d := abs(a - b)) <= tolerance:
        print(f'{label}-Coords Within Range: {d:.2}') 
        return True
    else:
        print(f'{label}-Coords Not Within Range: {d:.2}')
        return False

x1,y1 = get_xy(results,14)
x2,y2 = get_xy(results,15)
tol = .1
check('X',x1,x2,tol)
check('Y',y1,y2,tol)
```

```
X-Coords Within Range: 0.004
Y-Coords Within Range: 0.049
```